# Update a value of object value inside *ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I have this array of objects which holds bunch of comments:

```
  comments: Comment[];
```

And this array is filled up inside `ngOnInit()` function by invoking service code. Later on, there is a key in my `comments` array which is `commentPlus` among with other keys. This value represents the total upvotes for a comment. I use its value inside my html like this:

```
<div class="media mb-3" *ngFor="let comment of comments; trackBy: trackByFn">...
<a class="btn btn-success" (click)="upVote()" [ngClass]="{'active' : comment.voted > 0 }"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{comment.commentPlus}}</a>
```

What I want is to update the value `{{comment.commentPlus}}` and style of the button whenever user hits the button. Below is the code for `upVote()` function

```
upVote(commentId: number, userId: number){
    userId = this.userId;
    commentId = 4;    //I just assigned some number that I know it exists in my database for testing.
    this.service.upVote(commentId, userId).subscribe();
}
```

But the problem is that neither style change that should be performed by `[ngClass]="{'active' : comment.voted > 0 }"` nor new value for `{{comment.commentPlus}}` reflects in front end. Backend is working as it should be, but these two changes require page to be refreshed.

```
export class Yorum {
  commentId?: number;
  userId?: number;
  comment?: string;
  commentPlus?: number;
  commentMinus?: number;
  voted?: number;
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

well you should update you'r model after server response

change you'r html to

```
<div class="media mb-3" *ngFor="let comment of comments; trackBy: trackByFn">...
<a class="btn btn-success" (click)="upVote(comment)" [ngClass]="{'active' : comment.voted > 0 
}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> {{comment.commentPlus}}</a>
```

then

```
upVote(comment){
    userId = this.userId;
    commentId = 4;    //I suggest =====> commentId = comment.id
    this.service.upVote(commentId, userId).subscribe(
      data=>{
         if(data){ //it depend's on you'r server response :)
           comment.voted = 1 ; //for example 
           comment.commentPlus = 1 ; 
         }
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
}
```

and it's done.

Comment: how could I pass `comment` parameter to `upVote()` function? Its signature is `upVote(commentId: number, userId: number)`

Comment: of course you'r comment has id , so you can use `comment.id` inside you'r service instead of `commentId`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your `comments` array is being updated.

You could do 2 things:

1. Update your `comments` array with new values for the comment that you just updated, inside `this.service.upVote` subscribe's success callback.
2. Have an Rxjs `Subject` inside your service. Subscribe to this Subject inside your component's `OnInit` and inside it's success callback update your `comments` array. Broadcast new value on this Subject from inside `this.service.upVote` subscribe's success callback.

Comment: Actually I ve tried your first suggestion but I think I made something wrong. I ve tried to filter comments array based on commentId that is updated but it gave me nothing. Like this: `this.comments.filter('commentId': commentId )[0].commentPlus++;`

Comment: try this and build on to that:

```this.comments.map((comment) => {
      if (comment.commentId === 2) {
       comment.commentId = 4;
      }
    });```